# How do I publish a fat JAR (JAR with dependencies) using sbt and sbt-release?

Tags: deployment, jar, sbt, sbt-assembly

I need to build a single jar, including dependencies, for one of my sub-projects so that it can be used as a `javaagent`.

I have a multi-module sbt project and this particular module is the lowest level one (it's also pure Java).

**Can I (e.g. with [sbt-onejar](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-onejar), [sbt-proguard](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-proguard) or [sbt assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly)) override how the lowest level module is packaged?**

It looks like these tools are really designed to be a post-publish step, but I really need a (replacement or additional) published artefact to include the dependencies (but only for this one module).

**UPDATE:** [Publishing](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#publishing-not-recommended) for sbt-assembly are instructions for a single project, and doesn't easily translate into multi-project.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Publishing for sbt-assembly are instructions for a single project, and doesn't easily translate into multi-project.

People have been publishing fat JAR using sbt-assembly & sbt-release without issues. Here's a blog article from 2011: [Publishing fat jar created by sbt-assembly](http://yuesong.wordpress.com/2011/11/06/publishing-fat-jar-created-by-sbt-assembly/). It boils down to adding `addArtifact(Artifact(projectName, "assembly"), sbtassembly.AssemblyKeys.assembly)` to your `build.sbt` (note that the blog is a little out of date `AssemblyKeys` is now a member of `sbtassembly` directly).

For sbt 0.13 and above, I prefer to use `build.sbt` for multi-projects too, so I'd write it like:

```scala
import AssemblyKeys._

lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT",
  organization := "com.example",
  scalaVersion := "2.10.1"
)

val app = (project in file("app")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(assemblySettings: _*).
  settings(
    artifact in (Compile, assembly) ~= { art =>
      art.copy(`classifier` = Some("assembly"))
    }
  ).
  settings(addArtifact(artifact in (Compile, assembly), assembly).settings: _*)
```

See [Defining custom artifacts](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Artifacts.html#defining-custom-artifacts):

> addArtifact returns a sequence of settings (wrapped in a SettingsDefinition). In a full build configuration, usage looks like:
>
> ```
> ...
> lazy val proj = Project(...)
>   .settings( addArtifact(...).settings : _* )
> ...
> ```

Comment: thanks, but I get a compile error if I do that in the `build.scala`

Comment: “a compile error” — what compile error? can't offer help if we can see neither your code nor the error message

Comment: thanks Eugene, your edits fixed it (NOTE: we discussed this elsewhere and it turned out to be a typo in the docs).

Comment: Mine seems to be creating the assembly, but then publishing the packaged jar, but not the assembly jar.  Do you know what the issue might be?

Comment: @nickn it sounds like you're not setting a classifier for the assembled jar, so it defaults to the normal artficat name and then conflicts with the non-assembled jar being made/published first