# sbt publish assembly jar with a pom

Tags: sbt, pom.xml, sbt-assembly

I am able to build one of my multi-project's jars as a single jar and then publish it [How do I publish a fat JAR (JAR with dependencies) using sbt and sbt-release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23070469)

However, the associated `pom.xml` is **not** published with it.

**How can I create and publish the `pom.xml` (and ivy file) descriptors for an `sbt-assembly` jar?**

My project is [lions-share](https://github.com/fommil/lions-share).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to publish the contents of an existing *pom.xml* file, or can you let sbt generate the pom's contents for you?  If the latter, consider using [`pomExtra`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Community/Using-Sonatype.html#third-pom-metadata):

```
pomExtra := (
  <url>http://jsuereth.com/scala-arm</url>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>BSD-style</name>
      <url>http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>
  <scm>
    <url>git@github.com:jsuereth/scala-arm.git</url>
    <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:jsuereth/scala-arm.git</connection>
  </scm>
  <developers>
    <developer>
      <id>jsuereth</id>
      <name>Josh Suereth</name>
      <url>http://jsuereth.com</url>
    </developer>
  </developers>)
```

Comment: the poms for the main sub-projects are working fine. The issue here is that `sbt-assembly` publications have no descriptors at all.

Comment: Strange; it seems to work for me when I combine [this example](https://github.com/eed3si9n/sbt-assembly-full-config-sample) with the ["not recommended" publishing configuration](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#publishing-not-recommended).

Comment: I'm surprised the "not recommended" advice even compiles for you... the current maintainers had to give me the advice in the above to even get the jars building as part of the publish. What about on 0.13.2-RC2?

Comment: I have my `build.scala` in the question... see anything obvious?

Comment: I've done the same as you, but still no descriptors. I've updated the question with information. Are you sure you get descriptors produced? Did you modify the example a different way?

Comment: DOH! I'm an eejit... of course, `assembly` is a classifier, it's not a separate module!

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer, even though I was just being stupid, because otherwise the bounty is just wasted.

Comment: Thanks, and I'm glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

If you are making your fat jar via `sbt clean assembly` and want to include `.pom` with the jar, use `sbt clean makePom assembly`. This will automatically create the `.pom` file with the `.jar` file